# How to configure the Sender address in phpmailer library

Tags: php, phpmailer, mail-server, exim, dovecot

I'm not sure this question belongs to *serverfaults*. However I decided to post this here mainly because I am using php program to send emails.

My issue is to configuring the Sender part in phpmailer.

```
$mail->setFrom('info@mydomain.com',"My Company Inc")
$mail->addReplyTo('info@mydomain.com',"My Company Inc")
```

I put the above part in my code.
But when I checked the receiver's end, I see the header

```
Sender: <mydomain@mydomain.com>
```

but what I expected to see is

```
Sender: <info@mydomain.com>
```

I'm  running own mailserver using exim MTA and dovecot.

Could you suggest me how to overcome this OR help me figure out whether this has to do with mailserver configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
$mail->Sender = "info@mydomain.com";
```

?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer::Sender()

Comment: Thats what I get When I added Sender part.

Comment: @zram any other idea? appreciate your help.

Comment: @zram : And then I added exact thing you suggested it also shows the header Sender: <mydomain@mydomain.com> and thats not what I like to see.

Comment: This answer is correct, but it may be that your server does not allow setting arbitrary from addresses - for example gmail doesn't - and restricts you to the Username. Also you shouldn't be seeing a Sender header at the receiver end at all - it should be converted on receipt to a return-path.